# How to add an event to other person's Google Calendar with PHP API client?

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am working on a web application with a build-in agenda. I want to add the items that have been added in this build-in agenda, to the user's Google Agenda. But there is one thing I am wondering. How to get access to that user's Google Agenda?

I was able to get access to my own agenda by adding the *XXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com* email to the list of addresses that have access to my agenda. But asking everyone to do this isn't really user friendly.

So does someone know the best way to request access to another person's agenda so I can add events through the Google PHP API client?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Oauth tokens. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
and https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth